# how to extract the features from the rgb images without converting them to the gray image?

Tags: matlab

i want to extract the features from rgb facial images that to without converting them to the gray images? how should i do it?

Comment: This was answered in your last question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To repeat myself from your last question, you really really should not do it that way. Use cell arrays:

```
for i = 1:50
    img{i} = imread(['C:\Users\shree\Desktop\final data\target\' num2str(i) '.jpg']);
end

img_grey = cellfun(@rgb2gray, img, 'UniformOutput', false);
img_50 = cellfun(@(x)(imresize(x, [50, 50])), img, 'UniformOutput', false);

figure,imshow(img{35});
title('original');
figure,imshow(img_grey{35});
title('gray');
figure ,imshow(img_50{35});
title('resized');
```

If you use `evalc` you will end up with 1000 variables!!! How can you possibly work with that? Not to mention it's hard to debug, mlint won't pick up your errors. In a cell array it's super easy to apply a function too all your images in one line. Using a cell array is absolutly the correct way to proceed, if you carry on using `evalc` you are shooting yourself in the foot and creating waaay more work for yourself.

Comment: @Dan.hey dear i tried to use cell array but its showing following error...:(   Error using ==> cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.

Error in ==> t at 9
img_grey = cellfun(@rgb2gray, img);   i tried to resolve it but i really don't understand what should i do...

Comment: @arch fixed. The error literally tells you how to fix it.

Comment: sorry i really cannot fix it....:( as i said i am just started to use matlab....:(

Comment: @arch Did you see my edit though? I showed you how to fix it in my answer... are you saying that after adding `'UniformOutput', false` you are still getting and error? If so what error?

Comment: hurrreeeee.......Dan...!!! its working now....:) thanx a lot...

Comment: @Dan...really thanks verrryyyy much...:) i hope you will never mind if i keep on asking you doubts..:)

Comment: @arch no problem, if it works don't forget to mark it as solved (click the tick mark in the top left of the answer) and if you liked it come back and upvote when you get to 15 rep ;) (just don't use eval!)